# Web comic site with three languages?

Tags: website-design

I want to start a web comic site like [this one](http://www.asofterworld.com/). But I want  users to see English, Spanish and Chinese at the same time (so they can also learn).

Not sure how to arrange that. I want the user to feel comfortable reading them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you're absolutely set on the requirement to display three languages actually **at the same time**, with no toggling between them, then the texts need to be outside the drawing, not on top of it, nor in any kind of bubble. Or you can display three strips side by side. Maybe two of them faded out and brought into focus on mouseover. But IMO there's no way to put three languages inside a single frame and keep it sane.

Comment: 'Maybe two of them faded out and brought into focus on mouseover' This is actually a damn good idea thanks!